# handling ajax data with jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, autocomplete

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/rooms.json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        q: req.term
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert('test');
        responseFn($.map(data.room, function (item) {
            alert('test1')
            return {
                label: item.title
                value: item.title
            }
        }));
    }
});
```

data from `/rooms.json?q=a` looks like below:

```
[{
    "room": {
        "created_at": "2011-05-19T18:08:04Z",
        "title": "Great Office Space for Rent!",
        "cost": 450,
        "updated_at": "2011-05-19T18:08:04Z",
        "property_id": 4,
        "maximum_capacity": 234,
        "id": 15,
        "fulladdress": "550 12th St NW, Washington D.C., DC 20005, USA",
        "user_id": null,
        "phone": "301-395-7578",
        "description": "Great office space to rent in DC\r\n\r\nPlease contact. ",
        "email": "something@gmail.com"
    }
}]
```

In the above code, I see the first `alert` but not the second `alert` so something is going wrong in the handling of the data from the json request.

What should I do to fix this?

**Update**
After playing around w/ some code I figured it out.

I had to tweak the rails controller to render json as below

```
format.json {render :json => @events.map(&:attributes)}
```

Furthermore, for jQuery code I had to remove `.room` from the code below

```
responseFn($.map(data.room, function (item) {
```

Comment: Is `responseFn()` a jQuery function, or one you defined? Also, check the error log. Any errors?

Comment: responseFn() is part of jQueryUI autocomplete.  I figured it out after playing around with some tweaks. probably jumped the gun on posting the question.  I've updated it with answer for the next person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> silly me

in rails code:

```
format.json {render :json => @days.map(&:attributes)}
```

in jQuery code

```
responseFn( $.map( data, function( item ) {
```